# Jssor slider - transition examples from author website not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I'm not sure why, but when i copy paste transition from website, into this piece of code, transitions not appear on slider.   The only one transitions i run with success are those available in 
[Only this one working perfect](http://www.jssor.com/development/enable-slideshow.html).

Here is piece of code im using:
 `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
                {$Duration:1500,x:0.3,y:-0.3,$Delay:20,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Top:[0.2,0.8]},$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$Round:{$Left:0.8,$Top:2.5}},
                {$Duration:1500,x:0.3,y:-0.3,$Delay:20,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Top:[0.2,0.8]},$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$Round:{$Left:0.8,$Top:2.5}},
                {$Duration:1500,x:0.3,y:-0.3,$Delay:20,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Top:[0.2,0.8]},$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$Round:{$Left:0.8,$Top:2.5}},
            ];
            var options = {
                $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,
                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                //$SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
                $SlideDuration: 400,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
              // $SlideHeight: 791,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,`

```
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            },



                                 //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1,
                $Scale : false //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2     vertical, default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1 ,
                $Scale : false//[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

 //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window          resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();

            if (windowWidth) {
                var windowHeight = $(window).height();
                var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
                var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

                var scaleWidth = windowWidth;
                if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
                    scaleWidth = Math.ceil(windowHeight / originalHeight * originalWidth);
                }

                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(scaleWidth);
            }
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }


        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    });
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of jssor slider. And the doc you refer to is very old as well.

Please download the latest version (or at least v 17.0).

Note that new version uses new transition format, and it is compatible with old transition as well.